# Row-level revision control for Oracle?

Tags: oracle, logging, revision

I'm looking for an oracle package that will capture changes to a table and save them into a log or journal table.  For example, executing a sql statements such as

```
insert into foo(x,y) values (12,34);
```

would capture these actions into an appropriate table, something like:

```
timestamp          who     operation   column    value
---------          ---     ---------   ------    -----
12-JAN-2012 13:22  MH      insert      x         12
12-JAN-2012 13:22  MH      insert      y         13
```

It would be great if there were facilities to generate sql statements based on this information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using fine grained auditing:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/auditing.htm#DBSEG525

As an alternative you can also turn on a flashback archive for the tables in question. Then you can query the content of the table at any point in the past. That won't show you *who* did the change though (and how it was done).

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by a simple [trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm) on the target table that fires on insert. Something like this perhaps:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER foo_audit
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
        ...
    ELSIF UPDATING THEN
        ...
    ELSIF DELETING THEN
        ...
    END IF;

END;
/
```

The format of this kind of trigger is sufficiently simple that you could actually programatically generate them.